# C# capture a soap message when the return value of invoke is null

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, attributes

When the following proxy webservice returns a null value I need to store the returned soap message in my database against a particular UserID. 
I am currently capturing the soap message to a text file in the TraceExtension class. But since attribute metadata is constant I cannot pass the UserID to this class at runtime. Is there any workaround for this?

```
[ TraceExtensions.TraceExtension(), System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("qualifyServicesResponse", Namespace = "")]
public qualifyServicesResponse qualifyServices([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "")] qualifyServicesRequest qualifyServicesRequest, int UserID)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("qualifyServices", new object[] {
            qualifyServicesRequest, UserID});
    return ((qualifyServicesResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

The TraceExtension class looks like this:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)> _
Public Class TraceExtensionAttribute
    Inherits SoapExtensionAttribute

    Private m_filename As String = "C:\trace\log.xml"

End Class
```

And then we override the ProcessMessage in the SoapExtension class:

```
Public Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByVal message As SoapMessage)
    Select Case message.Stage
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize
            WriteOutput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize
            WriteInput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using message.GetInParameterValue in the BeforeSerialize to get the UserID:

```
Public Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByVal message As SoapMessage)

    Select Case message.Stage
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize
            UserID = Convert.ToInt32(message.GetInParameterValue(1))
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize
            WriteOutput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize
            WriteInput(message)
        Case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize
    End Select
End Sub
```